# Why is output only showing on 2 of my input boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to learn JQUERY/HTML, so I am making a shopping cart. I am trying to output subtotal, tax, shipping, and total cost to input boxes. The first 2, sub total and shipping cost show, but nothing is outputted for the last 2 input boxes.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="subTotal">
                <label for="subtotal"><span>Sub Total</span><span>*</span><input type="number" class="input-field" name="subtotal" id="subtotal" disabled/></label>
                <label for="shipping"><span>Shipping</span><span>*</span><input type="number" class="input-field" name="shipping" id="shipping" disabled/></label>
                <label for="tax"><span>Tax</span><span>*</span><input type="number" class="input-field" name="tax" id="taxCost" disabled/></label>
                <label for="total"><span>Total</span><span>*</span><input type="number" class="input-field" name="total" id="total" disabled/></label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
 function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    // iterate through each td based on class and add the values

    $(".cost").each(function () {

        var value = $(this).text();
        // add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(value);
        }

    });
    var subtotal = sum;
    var shippingCost = (sum * 0.085);
    var tax = (((sum + shipping) * 0.11));
    var total = (sum + shippingCost + tax);

    $("#subtotal").val(subtotal);
    $("#shipping").val(shippingCost);
    $("#taxCost").val(tax);
    $("#total").val(total);
};
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser?

Comment: @JoeLissner Nope, the rest of my site and scripts work fine, its just those 2 boxes that aren't showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this isn't a typo?

```
 var tax = (((sum + shipping) * 0.11));
```

Shouldn't it be

```
 var tax = (((sum + shippingCost) * 0.11));
```

Comment: Yes, good catch. Although #total was using the correct vars, and it still didn't output. I fixed #tax and it still doesn't output.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I tried to understand your code, first off I could not find `.cost` anywhere in the code so the output was `0` from the start, so I added a value to the inputs and then this.

This code block was your original code, the shipping variable is named wrongly, it's probably supposed to be `shippingCost`.

```
var tax = ((sum + shipping) * 0.11);
```

Here is the code.
https://jsfiddle.net/dbu41wpa/2/

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified. .cost is a column in my shopping cart table. It sums up all the items in the cost column. I realized the shippingCost mistake and fixed it, still no output.

Comment: Try the new code I added. Switch out $(input) in the code to .cost and it might work for you.

Comment: If this answer helped you, I would appreciate if you could accept it.